# Incorrect dates in react-date-range

Tags: reactjs, datetime, react-date-range

I am using [react-date-range](https://github.com/hypeserver/react-date-range) plugin to select a date range in a application. It is shown as follows.
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dfg8w.png)
How can I fix this incorrect dates?

I updated the package in the package.json, but that didn't help. Thanks for your help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By follow the [documentation](https://github.com/hypeserver/react-date-range#daterangepicker--daterange)
we can achieve this,
here is an example of the code

```
import { DateRangePicker } from 'react-date-range';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  handleSelect(ranges){
    console.log(ranges);
    // {
    //   selection: {
    //     startDate: [native Date Object],
    //     endDate: [native Date Object],
    //   }
    // }
  }
  render(){
    const selectionRange = {
      startDate: new Date(),
      endDate: new Date(),
      key: 'selection',
    }
    return (
      <DateRangePicker
        ranges={[selectionRange]}
        onChange={this.handleSelect}
      />
    )
  }
}
```